# How can we choose the best file type to save our CSV file as?

Tags: python, csv

I've always been using the .txt format to write my database as CSV files, but I'm curious if what I'm doing is somewhat irresponsible/not optimal and in which case would one file type be better than another? I've never had any issues with using .txt, but I'm just curious if someone has some deeper insights that could eventually help, at least I'll have that information somewhere in mind.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "file type"?  Do you mean the file extension?  Because the traditional and sensible extension for a CSV file is `x.csv`.  Remember that the file extension has no impact on the file at all.  It's just a name.

Comment: File formats have very little to do with file extensions, except for the fact that your OS or other applications might attempt to infer the format from the extension. In this case, the difference is only in the file extension, not the file format, so might as well go with something descriptive like `.csv`.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56269765/is-file-format-different-from-file-extension

Comment: Oh ok. I thought file extension had some relevance when it comes to optimization and stuff like that. I thought that maybe loading from a .txt is faster than loading from a .xls or whatnot.

Comment: An `.xls` extension indicates that the file format is likely to be Excel. That's an entirely different format than a standard plain text `.csv` file. File formats matter; extensions... not so much.

Comment: what do you mean that you use .txt format to write your database as .csv files? these are 2 different formats.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen why do you prefer .cvs pver .txt?

Comment: @Faindirnomainzein the very first sentence is really confusing, I advise you to edit your question and also add better tags and it will be seen and answered.

Comment: @Faindirnomainzein the very first sentence is really confusing, I advise you to edit your question and also add better tags and it will be seen and answered.